# translate vswscanf from c to c++?

Tags: c++, c, translate

I need to translate, vswscanf  function from c to c++
using wide string stream and var arg,
can you help me ?

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void GetWideMatches ( const wchar_t * str, const wchar_t * format, ... )
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  vswscanf (str, format, args);
  va_end (args);
}

int main ()
{
  int val;
  wchar_t buf[100];

  GetWideMatches ( L"99 bottles of beer on the wall", L" %d %ls ", &val, buf);

  wprintf (L"Product: %ls\nQuantity: %d\n", buf, val);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can put `#include <cstdio>` in C++ to use the C library into a C++ program. Just remove the `.h` extension and prefix the name of the library with `c`

The above code is plain `C` right?

Comment: right, but i don't know how to use var args and wide stream in c++; can you show me a simple example (for dummies...) !

Comment: Me neither actually. But you should be able to do something very similar. Have you just tried to include the library and define the var arg function the same as before? Does it give you an error?

Comment: there has been a misunderstanding , sorry for my english
if i include header , compiler comples in a right way.

what i want to do , is convert 'function' vswscanf
in a c++ way, using :
- wstringstream ;
- VariadicTemplate